# How to insert data into fusion table using php

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I am using fusion tables to generate pins over the map. now I want to insert more coordinates data into the table using php but couldn't get any exact idea how to do it?

Can anyone help me for that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I would like to respectfully suggest that answers that simply refer posters to the Fusion Table PHP Library may not be helpful to many and can be outright discouraging to some. The PHP Library is a tremendously impressive, interconnected set of scripts. It is also massive, mostly uncommented, and requiring many nested 'includes' and 'requires.' The whole thing must be over 2000 lines long and it is hard to even decipher which parts you need.

For the poster the starting point needs to be the Developer's Guide and the OAuth2 Guide. These are at:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/articles/oauthfusiontables

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide

Answer (score 0):

See the [Fusion Table PHP Library](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables-client-php/)